# Solving a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

Consider a machine that operates using the following equation:

**O** $_3\ _×\ _1 = $ **X** $_3\ _×\ _3  ×$ [**I** $_3\ _×\ _1$ −  **Y** $_3\ _×\ _1 $] + **Y** $_3\ _×\ _1,$

where **I** $_3\ _×\ _1$ is the input and **O** $_3\ _×\ _1$ is the output of this machine.
**X** $_3\ _×\ _3 $ and **Y** $_3\ _×\ _1 $ are fixed matrices. How can we determine the fixed parameters (**X** $_3\ _×\ _3 $ , **Y** $_3\ _×\ _1 $) using the input/output (**I** $_3\ _×\ _1 $ , **O** $_3\ _×\ _1 $)? How many pair of input/output is required to uniquely determine the fixed parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  how many components are you trying to determine?  Count the entries in the matrices.  How many equations do you get for each input/output pair?  How many pairs does it take to get enough?

Comment: Thanks @Ross Millikan.
Considering **I** $_3\_×\_1$ = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
i_1\_,\_1 \\i_2\_,\_1 \\i_3\_,\_1\end{array}\right)$,
**O** $_3\ _×\ _1$ = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
o_1\ _,\ _1 \\o_2\_,\_1 \\o_3\ _,\ _1\end{array}\right)$,
**X** $_3\ _×\ _1$ = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
x_1\ _,\ _1 & x_1\ _,\ _2 & x_1\ _,\ _3\\x_2\ _,\ _1 & x_2\ _,\ _2 & x_2\ _,\ _3\\x_3\ _,\ _1 & x_3\ _,\ _2 & x_3\ _,\ _3
\end{array}\right)$,
**Y** $_3\ _×\ _1$ = $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
y_1\ _,\ _1 \\y_2\ _,\ _1 \\y_3\ _,\ _1\end{array}\right)$,
for any input/output pair we have the following system of equations:

Comment: $\begin{array}{cc}
o_1\ _,\ _1 = x_1\ _,\ _1 × (i_1\ _,\ _1 - y_1\ _,\ _1) + x_1\ _,\ _2 × (i_2\ _,\ _1 - y_2\ _,\ _1) + x_1\ _,\ _3 × (i_3\ _,\ _1 - y_3\ _,\ _1)\\o_2\ _,\ _1 = x_2\ _,\ _1 × (i_1\ _,\ _1 - y_1\ _,\ _1) + x_2\ _,\ _2 × (i_2\ _,\ _1 - y_2\ _,\ _1) + x_2\ _,\ _3 × (i_3\ _,\ _1 - y_3\ _,\ _1)\\o_3\ _,\ _1 = x_3\ _,\ _1 × (i_1\ _,\ _1 - y_1\ _,\ _1) + x_3\ _,\ _2 × (i_2\ _,\ _1 - y_2\ _,\ _1) + x_3\ _,\ _3 × (i_3\ _,\ _1 - y_3\ _,\ _1)\end{array}$, So 4 input/output pairs are enough to determine the (**X** , **Y**).

Comment: is there any condition for choosing the input/output pairs. In other words, can we find a unique solution for (**X**,**Y**) using any chosen pair of input/output?

Comment: You are correct, you will have $12$ equations in $12$ unknowns if you use $4$ input/output pairs.  You run the risk of dependencies-you may find that one of your equations is linearly dependent on the others.  Certainly you do not want three of your input points in a line or all four to be in a plane.  I believe that will guarantee no dependencies unless they are built into **(X,Y)**-you have a basis of a $12$ dimensional vector space.